# does mysql offer append content to the value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to save user messages to a database. The message will be data **object ( class with fields text, sender, date)** that contains the message text with meta data:

- what is the most apperoperiate data type to store **object** (in this case message).
- could I append the content of one **object** (message) to another object without having to read the column value, update t in memory and write it back to disk.
  this is because I need to store all received message for user until user download them.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text will be type of `TEXT`
Sender should be sender Id in that case it will be `Int` or `Short Int`
and Date can be of type `DATE`,`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`
More info about DATE type goes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Your Message will be saved and retrieved in following format

```
to_id      sender_id     message                       date
22243       22211        blah blah   blah              3/3/2012
22244       22211        blah blah   blah              3/3/2012
22245       22211        blah blah   blah              3/3/2012
```

I cannot fully understand your second question.

How ever you can append data in your column in mysql using concat
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 4):

If there is a chance that the field may contain a null value, the following works:

```
UPDATE tb_messages 
SET message = CASE 
                WHEN LENGTH(message) > 0 THEN 
                  CONCAT(message, ',', 'New message content')  
                ELSE 'New message content' 
              END
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

For updating a field concating new text, you can use the [CONCAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Example:

```
UPDATE messages SET message = CONCAT(message, 'new text to add') where user_id = 1;
```

Please note this only works if the value of the existing field (in this example, 'message') is not NULL.

Comment: What a simple answer. Just what I was looking for.